# Change the date format for a column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, date

I would like to change the date format of a entire column in data frame.

My code looks like this:

```
fwds['fwdlookupterm'] = fwds['symbol'] + datetime.datetime.strptime(fwds['expiration_date'],'%y%m%d')
```

When i do so, i get an error:

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not Series
```

How to resolve this error?

Current code:

```
fwds['fwdlookupterm'] = fwds['symbol'] + pd.to_datetime(str(fwds['expiration_date']),format= '%y%m%d')
```

Current error:

```
Name: expiration_date, Length: 1266, dtype: object' does not match format '%y%m%d'
```

Comment: What is column `symbol` ? There are datetimes? Or there are strings? Can you add some sample data?

Comment: As the error says ```fwds['expiration_date']``` is an instance of ```Series``` and ```datetime.strptime()``` expects a ```String``` instead. What happens if you try ```datetime.datetime.strptime(str(fwds['expiration_date']),'%y%m%d')```?

Comment: @jezrael any idea on the problem?

Comment: @lakesh - Just read your comment, give me a sec.

Comment: @jezrael sure thanks!

Comment: @lakesh - So I am confused a bit - Do you want convert column to datetimes and then add `symbol` column filled strings? It is not possible, need both strings columns - like `fwds['fwdlookupterm'] = fwds['symbol'] + pd.to_datetime(fwds['expiration_date'].astype(str))`. Check how working converted to datetime - `fwds['fwdlookupterm'] = fwds['symbol'] + pd.to_datetime(fwds['expiration_date'],'%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: i want to combine both the columns. before combining, i want to change the format of the date. final output shld look like ISLEUR190208

Comment: the data type of both the columns are object

Comment: @lakesh - soory, I dont see comment, add jezreal before :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189042/discussion-between-lakesh-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need convert column to strings, then to datetimes and last to custom format by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
s = pd.to_datetime(fwds['expiration_date'].astype(str)).dt.strftime('%y%m%d')
fwds['fwdlookupterm'] = fwds['symbol'] + s
```

Comment: @lakesh - And `fwds['fwdlookupterm'] = fwds['symbol'] + pd.to_datetime(fwds['expiration_date'].astype(str))` ?

Comment: tried this as well: fwds['fwdlookupterm'] = fwds['symbol'] + pd.to_datetime(str(fwds['expiration_date']),format= '%y%m%d'). Have an error: Name: expiration_date, Length: 1266, dtype: object' does not match format '%y%m%d'

Comment: any idea on the problem?

Comment: @lakesh - check now, please